# Laravel Voyager: Access control for Bread Item

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm trying to limit the access to BREAD items. I have a table with below fields:

title
description
status

Now, i want only the admin user groups to edit the status field. Rest of the user group shouldn't be able to update the status. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please add more details and code. Read following link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Field wise privileges isnt available yet. You can do it by overriding views